# Remote desktop keyboard Windows Server 2019 switches to English after reconnect

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

I have the following issue when connecting to Windows Server 2019 over remote desktop:

- When I connect for the first time (= no disconnected session for my user exists), the keyboard on the remote server is correctly synchronized with my client PC = I have Czech keyboard set on both devices.
- However when I'm connecting to an existing *disconnected* session on Windows Server 2019, keyboard on the server is set to English. When I log off the session completely and then connect again, keyboard is synchronized properly until I disconnect and reconnect the session. Then it's swichted to English again. I can even see for a short moment in the GUI that keyboard on server is Czech and the immediately switched to English.

This is not happening on older versions of Windows Servers in our environment. I am also pretty sure it is not caused by group policies, because these are mostly the same for both Win 2016 and 2019. I have also tested moving the server to container where no policies are applied - same behavior. I have tested on couple of different servers and also connecting from different client OS and different tools (mstsc, rdcman, mRemoteNG). It always behaves like I described.

I am able to resolve this with manually adding Czech as default language in Settings. However this was not needed in Win Server 2016 so I wonder if this how Windows Server 2019 behaves for everyone or if it must be something in our environment?

Thanks for any suggestions what to try or check.

Answer (score 0):

we had exactly the same issue in our environment. We reported it to the MS and they released fix in below KB which solved above issue.

[KB5010427](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-15-2022-kb5010427-os-build-17763-2628-preview-d29de7d8-9646-486b-b9b1-c8e4fbe6bac0)

Addresses an issue that causes a mismatch between a Remote Desktop session’s keyboard and the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) client when signing in.